# menu is disordered when javascript executes

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on a ASP.NET application using .NET framework 4.0

I want to display javascript alerts when some code on the server finishes executing.

for example:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewAllocation.getSettings();
    NewAllocation.populateParentFundTable(FundNameTextBox.Text, RemarksTextBox.Text, Decimal.Parse(AmountTextBox.Text), DateTime.Parse(DateTextBox.Text), Decimal.Parse(SurplusTextBox.Text));
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"key","alert(\"New fund allocation successful\");",true);
}
```

I am calling the javascript code like this because **the javascript alert should only execute after the c# code in the button handler completes**.

The problem is, when the javascript alert executes, my menu gets disordered.

[image]

Whereas before clicking the button it was like this:

[image]

**My menu was designed in a master page using ASP.NET menu controls.**

How to solve the menu disorder problem?

Comment: Have you inspected the HTML output?

Comment: i cannot see the code for the menu bar in source view...i guess asp.net generates it in some special way...but i can see the code in firebug..it is usual menu code...li within ul and anchors within each li